# Ubuntu 16.04 with ZFS, more than 3000 process

Tags: 16.04, server, process, zfs

I have followed the tutorial : https://github.com/zfsonlinux/zfs/wiki/Ubuntu-16.04-Root-on-ZFS to install ZFS with Ubuntu.

Now I have the same issue on 3 different servers, lot of process (more than 3000)

I’m using zfs:

```
root@CH0064:~# cat /sys/module/zfs/version
0.6.5.6-0ubuntu16
```

Total process:

```
ps aux | wc -l  
3093
```

Around 450 for arc_prune :

```
ps aux | grep arc | wc -l  
452
```

for zfs:

```
ps aux | grep z_ | wc -l  
1646
```

fir metaslab_group_ :

```
root@CH0064:~# ps aux | grep meta | wc -l  
201
```

I ‘m using standard parameters  and I read that ZFS is using a lot of process but so lot I’m not sure

Any idea ?

Laurent